# Print hexa value in masm

Tags: windows, assembly, hex, masm32

I do a MapViewOfFile to get a pointer on the begin of my file, after that I want to print the value of it in hexa.

When I print it as string I get "MZ" which is the good value (the magic number) but I want it in hexa (5A4D).

I tried to format with %x in wsprintf but it doesn't work, I got 230000 as value..

EDIT the tried for %x:

```
.data
    header_format   db "The header is: %x",0 
    buffer          db 256 dup(?) ; File data
.data?
    pMemory DWORD ? ; Pointer to the data in the source file

getData:
    ;pMemory is the ptr which is correctly printed with %s
    invoke wsprintf, ADDR buffer, ADDR header_format, [pMemory] ; 
    invoke MessageBox, NULL, Addr buffer, Addr header_test, MB_OK
```

Have you any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Show how you tried `%x`. That should have worked.

Comment: @Jester  thanks for helping ! I edited the post with the code

Comment: You are *dereferencing* the pointer, instead of passing the address itself.

Comment: Hi @CodyGray, I tried with pMemory alone and Addr pMemory and I obtain the same result

Comment: Actually you are **not** dereferencing the pointer ... `%s` does that for you automatically, for integer you need to do that yourself. So try something like `mov eax, [pMemory]; invoke wsprintf, ADDR buffer, ADDR header_format, [eax]`

Comment: So I tried your solution and it doesn't compile at the invoke line with this error : "INVOKE argument type mismatch : argument : 0" so I tried this way : `mov eax, [pMemory]; mov pMemoryBis, eax; invoke wsprintf, ADDR buffer, ADDR header_format, [pMemoryBis]` and the result is the same, I have MZ with string and 230000 with %x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally works by using this solution :

```
push STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
call GetStdHandle

mov eax, pMemory
push eax
print   right$(uhex$(eax),2),13,10
pop eax
mov eax, pMemory
push eax
print   right$(uhex$([eax]),2),13,10
pop eax
```